# Obtaining a probability distribution after a change of variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $x_1,x_2$ whose distributions are unknown. I define $y_1=g(x_1,x_2)$ and $y_2=f(x_1,x_2)$ where $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are known and the probability distributions $p(y_1)$ and $p(y_2)$ are known. How could I obtain the joint probability?

One proposed:
$$
P(x_1,x_2)=\int\int P(y_2)P(y_1)\delta(y_2 -f(x_1,x_2))\;\delta(y_1 -g(x_1,x_2))dy_1dy_2
$$
However I am unable to derive the formula nor the reason behind it.
Thank you very much for your help! Any idea highly appreciated.

Comment: Intuitively it just means "integrate the joint density of $(y_1,y_2)$ and count only the pairs $(y_1,y_2)$ with $f(x_1,x_2)=y_2$ and $g(x_1,x_2)=y_1$" (since these are the values of $Y_1,Y_2$ that you must necessarily have if $(x_1,x_2)$ were the values of $(X_1,X_2)$ you had). In the continuous setting this is a little bit more complicated, and you need to actually use the definition of the composition of the Dirac delta with a function, but this identity still holds then (under some assumptions about $f,g$).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However I still have trouble seeing it. To me this integral will give me the distribution of $P(f(x_1,x_2)) \cdot P(g(x_1,x_2))$ and not the join $P(x_1,x_2)$. Why is this not the case?

Comment: The idea doesn't really depend on the dimension, so just think about the 1D case, $f_X(x)=\int f_Y(y) \delta(y-g(x)) dy$. This says that since $y$ is a function of $x$, $f_X(x)$ is $f_Y(g(x))/|g'(x)|$. In particular, the only value of $f_Y(y)$ that actually matters is $f_Y(g(x))$, since there's only one value of $y$ for our given value of $x$.

Comment: This approach is a lot more useful when you want the distribution of $g(X)$ when you know the distribution of $X$, because now there might be more than one value of $x$ for the same given value of $y$.